# mysql select a column as another column name which will have a fulltext index

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a double select (Sub query) like this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)
```

I want to select some column as something which will be of fulltext type like this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT column AS newname MAKE newname FULLTEXT)
```

In other words I need to have `newname` in `*` indexed as `FULLTEXT`:

Answer (score 1):

as i understand u may look for this

```
   ALTER TABLE your_table  ADD FULLTEXT(newname);
```

this will change the column `newname` to FULLTEXT

Comment: ...table is not existing it is being created virtually by SELECT

Comment: you want create table and have FULLTEXT  to newname ?

Comment: no. i want to assign a variable name with index named fulltext, not create a table with fulltext index on its column. it is already done.

Comment: sorry i give up i didnt understand really what u want. if you want change the column in some table then `ALTER` .